# Why does item in plist gets overwritten?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsarray, plist

I am trying to add a new item to my plist. However, it gets overwritten every time i press save:

```
-(IBAction)save:(id)sender {

 appDelegate = (JobTestAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]; 

 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *fileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Work.plist"];

 NSMutableDictionary* newNote = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];  

 NSMutableDictionary *set = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"", @"", nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Work Name", @"Work ID", nil]];

NSArray *work = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:set, nil];

int row = 0;
newNote = [appDelegate.job objectAtIndex:row];
[newNote setValue:work forKey:@"Work"];         

[appDelegate.job writeToFile:fileName atomically:TRUE];

[newNote release];  

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 }
```

I don't know which part of the code is wrong. I've been trying to solve the problem for days.

EDIT:
appDelegate.job - a mutable array in my main app delegate class to create the plist :

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Work.plist"];

job = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fileName];


[job writeToFile:fileName atomically:YES];
```

EDIT2:

I need to store the user input (NSArray*work) into the work array

> Root (Array)
>
> ```
>         Item 0 (Dict)
>                       Name (String)
>                       Work (Array)
>                                        Item 0 (Dict)
>                                                     Work Name (String)
>                                                     Work ID (String)
>                                        Item 1 (Dict)
>                                                     Work Name (String)
>                                                     Work ID (String)
>         Item 1 (Dict)
>                       Name (String)
>                       Analysis (Array)
>                                        Item 0 (Dict)
>                                                     Work Name (String)
>                                                     Work ID (String)
>                                        Item 1 (Dict)
>                                                     Work Name (String)
>                                                     Work ID (String)
> ```

Edit3:
    NSMutableDictionary* newNote = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

```
 NSMutableDictionary *set = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"", @"", nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Work Name", @"Work ID", nil]];

NSArray *work = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:set, nil];

int row = item;
newNote = [appDelegate.job objectAtIndex:row];
[newNote setValue:work forKey:@"Work"];         

//i think this is the line which i am having problem with.
//without this line my data in the plist gets overwritten, 
//with this code it copies the who item and create a new item into my root array
[appDelegate.job addObject:newNote];

[appDelegate.job writeToFile:fileName atomically:TRUE];

[newNote release];
```

Thanks in Advance,
Leanne

Comment: What is appDelegate.job? Can you post some code related to its manipulation?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply(: i have alr edited my question and post the code for appDelegate.job. Do you know what's missing or wrong in my code? Thanks(:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting whatever is at job index zero with your new item. You are also allocating memory here:

```
NSMutableDictionary* newNote = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

Then reassigning something else to this variable here:

```
newNote = [appDelegate.job objectAtIndex:row];
```

If you are trying to add a new item, you should be doing something like:

```
NSMutableDictionary* newNote = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[newNote setValue:work forKey:@"Work"];
[appDelegate.job addObject:newNote];
[appDelegate.job writeToFile:fileName atomically:TRUE];
```

You are then adding a new dictionary to your job array, and writing out the whole array.

EDIT: From your comments, it looks like newNote should be a dictionary, with a name and an array in it. So, you need to add a new object to the existing array - you are currently setting a single item array to the "work" key of this dictionary.

You need something like:

```
NSMutableDictionary* newNote = [appDelegate.job objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *oldWork = [newNote objectForKey:@"Work"];
NSArray *newWork = [oldWork arrayByAddingObject:set];
[newNote setObject:newWork forKey:@"Work"];
```

Comment: Thanks for replying(: The code above will save my code as an item in my root array however i want to store it into my work array (which is a child/sub key) shown in the plist above. How can i edit my codes to make it save new item into the work array instead of overwritting it? Thanks alot(:

Comment: Thanks(: but the code does work. i sort of know which part of my code the error happens. I've edited it. Can you help me take a look. Thanks

Comment: You are still overwriting the object for key @"work" with a brand new array. In my answer above I am taking the current array, then adding the new "set" dictionary to it, then reassigning that to the key @"work".